# Colored canvas qTip2 at its inception

Tags: jquery, canvas, qtip2

I would like to bring up a tip from the plugin QTip2 the color of my choice not include this color in the CSS code. This color is chosen at random to create the page and the user can change, so I need to find a way to bring up my tip with a well-defined color.

You can see my problem on this two Jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/thybomoon/fDavN/8801/ & http://jsfiddle.net/wHpvW/290/

```
function color() {
    var bulle_PA_argument = $("a").qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'bulle_check_A_1'
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-light'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'bottom center',
            at: 'top center',
            adjust: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            }
        },
        show: 'none',
        hide: 'unfocus'
    });
    var api_bulle_PA_argument = bulle_PA_argument.qtip('api');
    api_bulle_PA_argument.show();
    $('*').css('background', 'green')
        .css('border-color', 'green')
        .css('color', 'green');
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It just necessary to use set() like that :

```
var bulle_misska = $('#show').qtip({
content: {text: '<input type="button" value="Color me !" id="Color"/>'},
style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},show: 'none',hide: 'none'});
var api_bulle_misska = bulle_misska.qtip('api');
api_bulle_misska.show();

$(document).on('click', '#Color', Color);
function Color() {
    $('*').css('background-color','red')
    .css('color','blue')
    .css('border-color','blue');
    api_bulle_misska.set('style.tip.corner', true);
}
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/thybomoon/wHpvW/325/